# Breaking polymorphism?

Tags: java, groovy, rest-assured

A method from an object implementing an interface is not getting executed without explicit casting.

Broader context is that I'm trying to decorate RestAssured DSL assertions to anotate in a test report from an ad-hoc testing framework, so code like:

```
~then().assertThat().statusCode(200).body(matcher)
```

makes anotations in that sense in the test report.

As for decorator pattern I had little success (I assume my limited skills at developing), so I'm trying another simpler approach, which is passing the TestReport object in the then call, touching the Rest Assured codebase,  so now the syntax can be:

```
~then(report).assertThat().statusCode(200).body(matcher)
```

Down to specific point where I'm puzzled, which is apparently broken polymorphism, I tried setting a breakpoint at specific class (RestAssuredResponseImplementation) checked this is the actual type at runtime and assessed that it is not working without casting, throwing a java.lang.AbstractMethodError from the right method?!! io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl.then(TestCaseReport) which, of course, is not abstract.

- Involved snippets are;

  1. For the test definition:

     ```
     @Test
     public void test1(){
     Validatable validatable = given().
         header("Authorization", "Basic ASDFqwertyssW8=").
         when().
         get("https://some-site.org/login");
     validatable.then(report).
         assertThat().statusCode(200);
     }
     ```

     report object is provided, and, if you cast validatable object changing the line to:

     ```
     ((RestAssuredResponseImpl)validatable).then(report).
     ```

     everything works fine, otherwise I'm getting the aforementioned exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl.then(Report;)Lio/restassured/response/ValidatableResponseOptions;
```

2. Changes in RestAssured:

   1. interface Validatable T extends ValidatableResponseOptions adds:

      ```java
      T then(Report report);
      ```
   2. class ReportingValidatableResponseImpl extends ValidatableResponseImpl:

      ```java
      private TestCaseReport testCaseReport;

      ReportingValidatableResponseImpl(String contentType, ResponseParserRegistrar rpr, RestAssuredConfig config, Response response, ExtractableResponse<Response> extractableResponse, LogRepository logRepository, TestCaseReport testCaseReport) {
          super(contentType, rpr, config, response, extractableResponse, logRepository);
          this.testCaseReport = testCaseReport;
      }

      @Override
      ValidatableResponse statusCode(int expectedStatusCode) {
          testCaseReport.logMessage(LogStatus.INFO,"Asserting status code is " + expectedStatusCode)
          super.statusCode(expectedStatusCode)
      }
      ```

      3. Implementation on RestAssuredResponseImpl adds:

      ```
      ValidatableResponse then(TestCaseReport testCaseReport) {
           return new ReportingValidatableResponseImpl(contentType, rpr, config, this, this, logRepository, testCaseReport);
      }
      ```

If this is not a blunder from my side and I'm not missing something obvious, I would say this is breaking polymorphism and something very strange is happening here (I don't know where or how, since there is jUnit, Groovy involved, which implies heavy usage of reflection)

That's the use of interfaces, if at runtime, an object satisfies the interface, it doesn't matter which actual object it is.

I'm really puzzled about this, hope someone can bring some insight.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems weird to me. "AbstractMethodError: Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled."